# Subsetting on a numeric column in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My version of RStudio is Version 0.98.932, R is 3.1.1 and my version of data table is 1.9.4.

Below is a sample piece of code:

```
library(data.table)

TEMP <- data.table(SHOPPER_ID = c(953103325440, 953103325441))
TEMP[SHOPPER_ID == 953103325440]
```

I would expect a single row to be returned in the console:

```
##      SHOPPER_ID
## 1: 953103325440
```

However what R actually returns is:

```
##      SHOPPER_ID
## 1: 953103325440
## 2: 953103325441
```

I am not sure why this occurs and I was wondering if this is just an error I have or if it is a possible bug. When I convert the SHOPPER_ID column to a character variable I get what I expect to get.

A colleague of mine had an older version of data.table (< 1.9 I think) and he did not encounter the same type of error. Also if I run the following code:

```
unique(TEMP)
```

I get the desired result

```
##      SHOPPER_ID
## 1: 953103325440
```

Comment: Try  `TEMP[TEMP[,.I[SHOPPER_ID == 953103325440]]]`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get this behavior in an older version? That looks like a bug to me. Even binary search gives some strange result `setkey(data.table(SHOPPER_ID = c(953103325440, 953103325441)), SHOPPER_ID)[J(953103325440)]`

Comment: Please check `?setNumericRounding`. We recommend using `bit64::integer64` for such large (whole) numbers instead. I've opened an issue [#881](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/881) precisely to clear this. Will be documented in 1.9.6.

Comment: @DavidArenburg. I think I may have gotten it before but honestly can't remember what package. As I said, I got my colleague to try who had a version of data.table older than 1.9 and he didn't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
TEMP[TEMP$SHOPPER_ID == 953103325440, ]
```

Similarly the unique can be run on the column, `unique(TEMP$SHOPPER_ID)`